# Search through MVC search results

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC site that is connected to a database with multiple tables. Some of the tables have only 1000 or so records, so searching through those is fairly simple. However, one of the tables has over 2 million records, and I tried implementing the same searching method but it is far too slow. For the tables with less records, the search goes through every column looking for matches, but the table with a million records can only search through one column in an efficient manner. Essentially, what I want to do to fix this problem is to allow the user to search through the search results. So if I were to search by apple in the table with a million records, let's say that 100,000 records remain. Then, I could search by Gala on the remaining 100,000 records to narrow the results down even more. Is this possible? Or is there possibly a better way to search through this many records that I am not thinking of?

Controller

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string search, int? page, int? pageSize)
        {
            int pageIndex = 1;
        pageIndex = page.HasValue? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;

            int defaSize = (pageSize ?? 25);
        ViewBag.psize = defaSize;

            ViewBag.PageSize = new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "25",Text = "25"},
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "50",Text = "50"},
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "100",Text = "100"},
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "1000",Text = "1000"},
            };


    ViewData["ControllerName"] = this.ToString();

    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;

    ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "pkDeviceUnderTest" : "";
            if (search == null)
            {
        ViewBag.TotalCount = dbModel.DeviceUnderTests.Count();



    }
            else
            {
        var ld = dbModel.DeviceUnderTests.Where(x => x.nkDeviceUnderTest.Contains(search)||x.nkNotes.Contains(search)||x.FaultApplication.nkFaultApplication.Contains(search)||x.Firmware.nkFirmware.Contains(search)
        ||x.Hardware.nkHardware.Contains(search)||x.Location.nkLocation.Contains(search)||x.Power.nkPower.Contains(search)||x.nkHandleRating.ToString().Contains(search)||x.nkPreEventTime.ToString().Contains(search)).ToList()

         .Count();

        ViewBag.TotalCount = ld;
    }

    ViewBag.cf = currentFilter;
    ViewBag.search = search;
            Session["searchcircuit"] = search;
    ViewBag.defaSize = defaSize;
    var div = ViewBag.TotalCount / defaSize;
    ViewBag.numofPages = ((ViewBag.defaSize - 1) + ViewBag.TotalCount) / ViewBag.defaSize;
    ViewBag.index = pageIndex;

            int pagenum = pageIndex;
    var records = dbModel.DeviceUnderTests.Where(x => x.nkDeviceUnderTest.Contains(search) || x.nkNotes.Contains(search) || x.FaultApplication.nkFaultApplication.Contains(search) || x.Firmware.nkFirmware.Contains(search)
        || x.Hardware.nkHardware.Contains(search) || x.Location.nkLocation.Contains(search) || x.Power.nkPower.Contains(search) || x.nkHandleRating.ToString().Contains(search) ||search==null|| x.nkPreEventTime.ToString().Contains(search)).OrderBy(x => x.pkDeviceUnderTest).Skip(defaSize * (pagenum - 1)).Take(defaSize);
    var result = new StaticPagedList<DeviceUnderTest>(records, pageIndex, defaSize, ViewBag.TotalCount);
            return View(result);
}
```

View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Circuit", FormMethod.Get))
                {
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search ... " />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:#337ab7;color:azure" />


                }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `db` multiple times. You can easily assign `ld` from `records`? From database level, try indexing if it may help.

Comment: Why you don't use stored proc on SQL side and then you call it with the search param